# To comment, or not?

Tags: bug, comments, locked

I'm getting conflicting signals here.  The post notice instructs me to leave a comment, but I get an error message when I try to do so.

[image]

I was the last person to issue a close vote for this question. After the question was closed the gray box appeared telling me to comment. I clicked the comment link which activated the usual comment box. Then typed my comment and clicked on the Add Comment button with the mouse. That is when the red box appeared.

Comment: Did you refresh the page? If yes, what happened then, locked, able to comment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was simply a matter of timing. The prompt to comment doesn't get deleted from the page when the post has been deleted.

Comment: @KateGregory: While I think you could lighten up a bit, especially considering you recognized I was trying to be humorous, I do apologize for any offense I may have caused.

Comment: Your freehand circles suck.

Answer (score 4):

The post was locked, deleted, or frozen after the page was loaded.  At the time the page was rendered suggesting a comment was entirely appropriate, and the check when submitting it indicates that it no longer is.

I fail to see a preferable way of going about dealing with this case.

Comment: I added additional details to the question.

Comment: @Dan-o And was the question in fact locked, deleted, or frozen when you refreshed the page?  The fact that you just cast a close vote doesn't change my answer at all.  If the question was not in fact deleted, locked, or frozen at that point in time when the error message says that it is then that would be a bug irrelevant of the close reason text.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It looks like it was deleted between the time it was put on hold and the time I tried to comment.. which was like 2 seconds.  Thus my confusion.